# Why TypeScript excepts a correct return of a overriden method, even though it's not reachable?

Tags: typescript, overloading, abstract-class

I've implemented an abstract, generic RESTClient. Sometimes not all REST actions are implemented, so I want to throw an error in that case.

If I override the method TypeScript expects me to return the specified type, even though I throw the error. If I add `return null` it compiles, but the return is unreachable.

```
export class RESTClient<E extends { id: number }, D = Omit<E, 'id'>> extends Client {
  protected path: string;
  public constructor(path: string, token?: string) {
    super(token);
    this.path = path;
  }

  public update(entity: E) {
    return this.clientInstance.put<E>(`${this.path}/${entity.id}`, entity);
  }
}

export class ItemClient extends RESTClient<Item> {
  public constructor(token?: string) {
    super('items', token);
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  public delete(_entity: Item) {
    throw new Error('Not supported by API');
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

How can I correctly implement this in TypeScript (version `3.7.2`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) as the return type for the implementing method. It's assignable to every other type:

```
interface Item { 
  id: number;
}

export class RESTClient<E extends { id: number }> {
  public update(entity: E) {
    return entity;
  }
}

export class ItemClient extends RESTClient<Item> {
  public update(entity: Item): never {
    throw new Error('Not supported by API');
  }
}
```

The suitable excerpt from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never):

> The `never` type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, `never` (except `never` itself). Even `any` isn’t assignable to `never`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that `never` is allowed in this case, because I thought the signature of the method must match the inherited one. Thank you for teaching me that! (Finally I can use this cool `never` type)